# Date Format changes when posting data to web api controller in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: post, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am posting data to my web api, one of the parameters I am posting is a date selecteed by a date picker.

Below is the post data to the action (got these values from firebug)

> EndDate : "18/10/2012" (Note: the format is : dd/mm/yyyy)
>
> ABC : "do not bother..."
>
> XYZ : "do not bother..."
>
> LMNO : "do not bother..."

Now in my controller I have a class with the above 3 string fields and one date field

```
public class PostModel{

  public string ABC {get;set;}
  public string XYZ {get;set;}
  public string LMNO {get;set;}
  public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
}
```

in my web api which looks somewhat like the one shown below

```
public Something PostSomething(PostModel model)
{}
```

**here I am getting the value of EndDate in the format of "mm/dd/yyyy". What I want is "dd/mm/yyyy".**

So for this I have also added a entry in the web.config file as follows...

```
<system.web>
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

This still doesnt help, please can someone tell me what wrong I am doing ?

**MORE SHOCKING DISCOVERY !!!**

I just tried this out with a normal controller instead of web api controller and it worked for the non - api controller. Has any body else come across this problem ??

For the normal action (non web api) I didnt even had to set any culture for this.

please help.

Comment: There are some solutions suggested here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1840662.aspx/1?Posting+UK+DateTime+format. But none of them doesn't seem to solve the issue entirelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my End Date date time field to string and then posted this end date as string to my controller.

Then in controller converted this string to date using `DateTime.Parse()`.

I know that this not the best solution one would want, but this gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you can tweak your JsonSerializerSettings on the JsonMediaTypeFormatter.

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = ...